# Why can't i connect two sockets using socket programming in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, websocket, socketserver, python-sockets

I have written code using sockets in python in two devices , one is programmed with client code(desktop) and another one is server code (laptop) both are connected over wifi , in client code i have given server ip address with port number, any thoughts on whats wrong??

Comment: You need to append a sample of the code

Comment: possible issues: firewall. binding to localhost.  Please share the code and client connection error (is it timeout or connection refused?).